Realloc fails, but only when a printf statement is used: "invalid next size"
I am trying to write a ThreadPool library for C; mostly for educational purposes, but also perhaps for practical usage later.  I have an implementation that "works", in that I can spin up the required number of threads into a waiting state, and then populate them from a queue of tasks.
The last feature I added was to allow the task queue to expand dynamically (using realloc) if the number of tasks added to the queue would exceed its capacity.  Y'know, the usual dynamic array stuff.
This works well with the following main function:
int main(void) {
  srand((unsigned int)time(0));

  sdm_threadpool_t *pool = sdm_threadpool_create(NUM_THREADS, DEFAULT_QUEUE_LENGTH);

  WrapperArg arg[NUM_TASKS] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TASKS; i++) {
    arg[i].input = i;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TASKS; i++) {
    // printf("Submitting job %d...\n", i);
    sdm_threadpool_add(pool, function_wrapper, &(arg[i]));
  }

  sdm_threadpool_join(pool);

  for (size_t i=0; i<NUM_TASKS; i++) {
    printf("arg[%zu].input = %d :: arg[%zu].output = %d\n",
           i, arg[i].input, i, arg[i].output);
  }

  return 0;
}

Note the commented-out printf just before the sdm_threadpool_add call.  If I remove the comments and allow this to print, I get a core dump with realloc(): invalid next size.  Or, I should say, I very often get a core dump, but not always.
From browsing around I suspect that I am doing something wrong with a pointer somewhere that is corrupting the heap, but I can't figure out where.  To be frank, I can't even think about how to go about investigating this to narrow down the problem.
Any advice you can give that pinpoints my mistake or that helps me investigate it myself would be gratefully received.
Thanks

Here are some definitions that are needed to compile the code:
typedef struct {
  void (*function)(void *);
  void *arg;
} sdm_threadpool_task_t;

typedef struct {
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
  pthread_cond_t notify;
  pthread_t *threads;
  sdm_threadpool_task_t *task_queue;
  size_t num_threads;
  size_t queue_capacity;
  size_t next_in_queue;
  size_t queue_length;
  size_t waiting_in_queue;
  bool shutdown;
} sdm_threadpool_t;

int slow_square(int n) {
  unsigned int sleepy_time = (unsigned int)rand() % 2000000;
  usleep(sleepy_time);
  int n_sqr = n*n;
  return n_sqr;
}

typedef struct {
  int input;
  int output;
} WrapperArg;

void function_wrapper(void *arg) {
  WrapperArg *cast_arg = (WrapperArg *)arg;

  cast_arg->output = slow_square(cast_arg->input);
}

Since I suspect it will be useful, I also include the code for the various functions I use in my little library.
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "cthreadpool.h"

void *sdm_threadpool_thread(void *threadpool);

sdm_threadpool_t *sdm_threadpool_create(size_t num_threads, size_t queue_capacity) {
  sdm_threadpool_t *pool = NULL;

  pool = malloc(sizeof(sdm_threadpool_t));
  if (pool == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem. Quiting\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  memset(pool, 0, sizeof(sdm_threadpool_t));

  pool->threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * num_threads);
  if (pool->threads == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem. Quiting\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  memset(pool->threads, 0, pool->num_threads * sizeof(pool->threads[0]));

  pool->task_queue = malloc(sizeof(sdm_threadpool_task_t) * queue_capacity);
  if (pool->task_queue == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem. Quiting\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  memset(pool->task_queue, 0, pool->num_threads * sizeof(pool->task_queue[0]));

  pool->num_threads = num_threads;
  pool->queue_capacity = queue_capacity;

  pthread_mutex_init(&(pool->lock), NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&(pool->notify), NULL);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_create(&(pool->threads[i]), NULL, &sdm_threadpool_thread, (void*)pool);
  }

  return pool;
}

int sdm_threadpool_add(sdm_threadpool_t *pool, void (*function)(void *), void *arg) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&(pool->lock));

  while (pool->waiting_in_queue >= pool->queue_capacity) {
    pool->queue_capacity *= 2;
    size_t new_size = sizeof(sdm_threadpool_task_t) * pool->queue_capacity;
    printf("Extending queue to %zu bytes\n", new_size);
    sdm_threadpool_task_t *new_task_queue = realloc(pool->task_queue, new_size);
    if (new_task_queue == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem. Quiting\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    pool->task_queue = new_task_queue;
  }

  pool->task_queue[pool->queue_length].function = function;
  pool->task_queue[pool->queue_length].arg = arg;
  pool->queue_length++;
  pool->waiting_in_queue++;

  pthread_cond_broadcast(&(pool->notify));
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->lock));

  return 0;
}

void *sdm_threadpool_thread(void *threadpool) {
  sdm_threadpool_t *pool = (sdm_threadpool_t *)threadpool;

  while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(pool->lock));

    while ((pool->waiting_in_queue == 0) && (!pool->shutdown)) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&(pool->notify), &(pool->lock));
    }

    if (pool->shutdown) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->lock));
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    void (*function)(void *) = pool->task_queue[pool->next_in_queue].function;
    void *arg = pool->task_queue[pool->next_in_queue].arg;
    pool->next_in_queue++;
    pool->waiting_in_queue--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->lock));

    function(arg);
  }

  return NULL;
}

void sdm_threadpool_join(sdm_threadpool_t *pool) {
  while (pool->waiting_in_queue > 0) {
    usleep(1000);
  }

  sdm_threadpool_destroy(pool);
}

void sdm_threadpool_destroy(sdm_threadpool_t *pool) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&(pool->lock));

  pool->shutdown = true;

  pthread_cond_broadcast(&(pool->notify));
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->lock));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < pool->num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(pool->threads[i], NULL);
  }

  free(pool->threads);
  free(pool->task_queue);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&(pool->lock));
  pthread_cond_destroy(&(pool->notify));
  free(pool);
}


Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Aside: you can simplify the code by using calloc() instead of malloc() followed by memset().

Thanks @TobySpeight.  I'm sorry if I have done something incorrect.  I believe that the main function is fairly minimal.  I added the additional code as a sort of "appendix" since I suspected that people would immediately ask for those definitions.  Perhaps I should remove that large block?

Bug? I see you are using num_threads for the malloc() but pool->num_threads for the memset(). But pool->num_threads is not set until the next line.

Yes @WeatherVane.  Great catch!  It is indeed a bug.  Just sadly not the bug that is causing the intermittent realloc error :(
(But thanks for catching that!)

Your code seems not to compile without that "extra" code, so it wouldn't be a complete example if you removed it (actually, it's already incomplete, since there's no definitions in scope for srand, time or printf).  What you should do is reduce the code to the smallest possible complete program that exhibits the problem (that's always a worthwhile thing to do - quite often I find the cause during that process of simplification, for example).

pool->queue_length and pool->next_in_queue are always increasing, but pool->waiting_in_queue is both increasing and decreasing. It is possible for pool->queue_length to reach and pass pool->queue_capacity, resulting in buffer overrun.

The array should be used as a circular queue. It is possible to increase the capacity of a circular queue array by moving the contents of any wrapped around elements after increasing the capacity.

@IanAbbott  Aha.  Interesting.  I wonder if I could ask you to sketch out a rough idea of what that might look like?

Sure. Let front be the index where the next item is removed from the queue, and back be the index where a new item is added to the queue. If the capacity is not exceeded, front and back will increment modulo the capacity. If a new item is to be added when the queue is full, and old_capacity is the old capacity, then if back <= front and back > 0 then after increasing the capacity, the elements from indices 0 to back-1 inclusive need to be moved to indices old_capacity to old_capacity+back-1 inclusive and then add old_capacity to back.

… And if the queue is full and back == 0, then the only thing that needs to be done after increasing the capacity is to set back = old_capacity.

You're calling rand from a thread function. You need to use the reentrant version: rand_r

Thanks to @IanAbbott I found the bug.  It was in the comparison I used to determine if the queue needed to be realloc'ed.  I've answered my own question now, but would like to give the credit to Ian.  Thanks!

A comment by IanAbbott led me to the bug.  The issue is the comparison I was doing to decide whether or not the queue needed to be realloc'ed.  I was comparing against pool->waiting_in_queue, which is incorrect since this is the number of unstarted jobs.  What I needed to do was this:
  while (pool->queue_length >= pool->queue_capacity) {

That is, comparing the length of the queue itself, and not the number of unstarted jobs.
Thanks for all the helpful comments and advice :)
